# How can I confirm the user limit of my google cloud/API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I recently received a email from Google named "Action required: Problem with your Google API project XXXX (id: XXXX)".

It is said:

> As of May 22, apps requesting risky OAuth scopes that have not completed the OAuth developer verification process are limited to 100 new user grants.
>
> Your Google Cloud/APIs project XXXX (id: XXXX) has not completed this process and has reached 60% of this user limit.

I want to confirm my user limit, so, how can I find my "new user grants" in my Google Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 100 new user grant limit because your [app is unverified](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865).

You'll have to [request verification for your app](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865#verification) and follow the verification process for this limit to dissapear.

Comment: I just want to know where to find my granted users.

Comment: @XiaoheFeng if you want to know a more detailed view of your APIs quotas (which is what the alert is referring to), you'll have to go to the "APIs & Services" menu. There you can see a brief summary of the quotas your users are requesting and if you click on one, you'll see a more detailed summary, were you can see info about the users and the quotas. If you want more info, you may have to contact GCP Support.

Comment: @GuillermoCacheda terrible - if Google has a limit they need to make the utilization of that limit CRYSTAL CLEAR