# Google OAuth - How to check which users are connected, and manually disconnect them?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm struggling with a the new OAuth verification process that Google has introduced. Earlier, my OAuth app was using sensitive scopes, and I made changes to ensure that the sensitive scopes are no longer required, and removed them from the OAuth consent screen configuration.

However, my OAuth consent screen is still being forced to go through the verification process (which is a black box and never seems to complete!)

**I noticed the following user-cap being breached. Could the forced verification be because of this? How do I check which users are connected to my app, and also manually disconnect them?** I have never bothered about this user-cap in the past, so it is quite possible that a number of these are internal/test users when the app was under active development and was being tested in production. Btw, if app simply deletes a user's `refreshToken` from the DB, and the user is forced to re-connect, will that count as `+2` or `+1` while calculating users against this cap?

[image: 100 out of 100 users]

Possibly related to [How can I confirm the user limit of my google cloud/API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664725/how-can-i-confirm-the-user-limit-of-my-google-cloud-api) -- but that doesn't answer this question in detail.

Comment: You (your code) have to track the users that you have authorized via your client. There is no API to track this besides your own services. You do not control or have access to Google Accounts information beyond that provided by the OAuth Identity Token. Refresh Tokens are not part of tracking. Is is the unique ID of the user's account that is counted towards the user cap.

Comment: Although you can logout a user from Google Accounts that action logs the user out of all of the sites that they use the Google Account at. This would upset some users and surprise others.

Comment: @DaImTo I posted my comment before you or at the same time you were posting. I did not see your answer at the time I posted my comment. Otherwise your answer is good. I upvoted your answer once I saw it.

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed the following user-cap being breached. Could the forced verification be because of this?

probably but only google can really anwser that

> How do I check which users are connected to my app, and also manually disconnect them?

You cant there is no way for you to know what users where connected to your app and disconnect them unless you have saved a refresh token for these users if you have then you could remove them using the revoke command.

However this is no guarantee  that the number google is displaying is going to change as it could be just a running total of users who have consented to your application in the past and not the ones who have currently consented.  There is no way of know ing this as google hasnt told use.

> if app simply deletes a user's refreshToken from the DB, and the user is forced to re-connect, will that count as +2 or +1 while calculating users against this cap

This may be true but that doesn't mean that the user has revoked your access to their application though their account.  The only way to remove access is for the user to remove it in their account or for you to use the revoke endpoint to revoke them by force.  Your application not having a refresh token doesn't mean that the user hasn't granted your application access.

Long story short your going to have to go though the verification process and wait for google to remove it when they see that you are no longer using the scopes that would require it.

Update: I have pinged someone on the team to see if this is working as intended or if it could be a bug. I will update this when i know more.

Comment: Thank you! Just curious - do you work AT Google or CLOSELY with Google?

Comment: I'm a Google developers expert for identity platform.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda - I am also a Google Developers Expert for Cloud Platform. My speciality is security, identity, authorization and networking.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda I am getting shuffled around between googles currently i am trying to find someone to give us a response on this.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda it would seam google does not feel like there is any bug here if you remove the scopes then you will be able to use your app again the hold will be removed even though you are saying it wasnt. I suspect that you will have to go though the verification process which will show google the bug.

Comment: @DaImTo thank you for your reply. Is there any way to speed-up the verification process? It has been more than 6 weeks since we submitted the relevant application.

Comment: None it took me six months to get verified for Youtube. or to even here a response.